# C++: Modify a vector of share_ptr elements

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

In a C++ program, I declare a variable *e* in this way:

```
shared_ptr<c_t> e = shared_ptr<c_t> (new c_t);
```

Then, *e* is initialized.

Later in the program, I want to resize *e*, using this function:

```
e->change(4);
```

Where the class *c_t* and the function *c_t::change* are defined as:

```
class c_t {

    public:
    vector<shared_ptr<double>> m;

    void change(int n) {
        vector<shared_ptr<c_double>> mm;
        shared_ptr<double> m_buffer = make_shared<c_double>();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            m_buffer = 3.14 * i;
            mm.push_back(m_buffer);
        };
        m = mm;
    };
};
```

However, this approach does not work.  When I use an iterator to read *e*, I get that the values of *e* are *inf*. Why? How should I change *e*?

**Edit:**
To read, actually to scale, the values of *e*, the class *c_t* uses this function:

```
void scaling(double factor) {
    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        m *= factor;
    };
};
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `double` with `c_double`? Are they the same type? Why different names then?

Comment: Sorry, this is only a dummy example. The real classes are more complex.

Comment: Also what do you mean use an iterator to read e? Is e in a container? Show us the code where you read e. ps: even if this is a dummy example, make it [complete and vertifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: shared_ptr<c_t>, and c_t contains a vector of shared_ptr? is it supposed to be so, or are you using too many shared_ptr<shared_ptr<container<...?

Comment: @Exceptyon It is supposed to be so.

Comment: `shared_ptr<c_t> e = shared_ptr<c_t> (new c_t);` is the initialization of `e`. What did you mean by "Then, `e` is initialized" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m_buffer = 3.14 * i;
```

`m_buffer` is of type `std::shared_ptr`. Your assignement makes no sense. You probably wanted to write:

```
*m_buffer = 3.14 * i;
```

Also you want to declare `m_buffer` inside the for loop so the values in the vector will have different values based on `i`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::shared_ptr<double> m_buffer = std::make_shared<double>();
    *m_buffer = 3.14 * i;
    mm.push_back(m_buffer);
};
```

Or a shorter version:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    mm.push_back(std::make_shared<double>(3.14 * i));
};
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f7add0ba6f6f419)

Comment: @Medicalphysicist Are you saying this didn't answer your question? Because the code compiles and works. There is no problem in your edited question any more.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use vector::assign?

```
m.assign(newSize, m_buffer);
```